# SSRS 2008 SQL statement help needed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I'm hoping someone can help me here.  I have a report that will be run by either a single salesrep, a Regional Sales Manager (that has several salesreps that report to him) and "all over" managers that should be able to see ALL the salesreps.  If the user is a salesrep, he should only be able to see the customers assigned to him; if the user is a Regional Manager, he should see his customers as well as all the other customers assigned to the reps that he manages; and the "all over" manager should be able to see every single salerep and all their customers.

We have a salesrep table (SALESMAN_MSID) that has their salesrep #, their MSID value, their Regional Manager rep #, and the type of user they are -- "S" means they are a salesrep, "R" means they are a Regional Manager, and "M" means they are an all over manager.  Here is the query I've got so far:

```
select distinct s.slsm_num, s.slsm_desc
from salesman s
where
    s.slsm_num in (select distinct slsm_num
                    from salesman_msid
                    where slsm_mgr_id = (@SlsmnRealNum))      
    or (s.slsm_num = (@SlsmnRealNum))
order  by s.slsm_desc
```

This works great if the user is a salesrep or a Reg Mgr, but I can't figure out how to write the sql to get the all over results to work.  The value that is in the parameter "@SlsmnRealNum" is their real salesrep #.

The values in the SALESMAN_MSDI table are as such:

```
Slsm_num    MSID        Slsm_mgr_id       User_Type
------------------------------------------------------
1379       ljones        1316                S
1316       pcuday        1316                R
1401       mmay                              M
```

if I add in the clause "or user_type = 'M', I get ALL reps back regardless of if I'm testing as a S or a R.

Can anyone help with the SQL statement to get the "M's" to return all but the other 2 to return as they should?

ETA:  here's the new sql statement (couldn't fit it in my comment??) -- thanks again to @Sklivvz!
 SELECT DISTINCT S.SLSM_NUM, S.SLSM_DESC FROM SALESMAN S WHERE S.SLSM_NUM IN (SELECT DISTINCT M.slsm_num
  FROM SALESMAN_MSID M
 WHERE M.slsm_num = (@SlsmnRealNum)  --Themselves
    OR (m.slsm_mgr_id = (@SlsmnRealNum) AND EXISTS -- Their subordinates if type R
        (SELECT 1 
           FROM SALESMAN_MSID m
          WHERE m.slsm_num = (@SlsmnRealNum) 
            AND m.User_Type = 'R'))
    OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 -- Everyone if type M
          FROM SALESMAN_MSID M
         WHERE m.slsm_num = (@SlsmnRealNum)
           AND m.USER_TYPE = 'M')) order by s.slsm_desc`enter code here`

Answer (score 1):

You need to subquery the table to differentiate the type:

```
SELECT DISTINCT slsm_num, slsm_desc
  FROM salesman
 WHERE slsm_num = @SlsmnRealNum  --Themselves
    OR (slsm_mgr_id = @SlsmnRealNum AND EXISTS -- Their subordinates if type R
        (
         SELECT 1 
           FROM salesman 
          WHERE slsm_num = @SlsmnRealNum 
            AND User_Type = 'R'
        )
       )
    OR EXISTS ( -- Everyone if type M
        SELECT 1 
          FROM salesman 
         WHERE slsm_num = @SlsmnRealNum 
           AND User_Type = 'M'
    )
```

Comment: you're the greatest!!!! THANK YOU!  :)  I did have to change it up a bit to get what I needed since the slsm_mgr_id and user_type are on the salesman_msid table and the other info is from the salesman table:

Comment: any chance you can help again? If the user_type is M then I only want to return records for user_types R or S.  Here's my query: SELECT DISTINCT S.SLSM_NUM, S.SLSM_DESC FROM SALESMAN S WHERE S.SLSM_NUM IN (SELECT DISTINCT M.slsm_num FROM SALESMAN_MSID M WHERE M.slsm_num = '9999' OR (m.slsm_mgr_id = '9999' AND EXISTS     (SELECT 1 FROM SALESMAN_MSID m
          WHERE m.slsm_num = '9999' 
            AND m.User_Type = 'R')
    OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 -- Everyone if type M
          FROM SALESMAN_MSID M
         WHERE m.slsm_num = '9999'
           AND m.USER_TYPE = 'M') order by s.slsm_desc